# Inconsistency in String split array result in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Note: The issue I am mentioning here is happening only in IE (I have used IE 11). It works fine as expected in all other browsers

Issue Description:
I am using string split method to split a string using delimitter. In my case, delimitter is "/".

The split worked as expected. However, when I take the values out of the result array for some comparison, it gave me strange results. I have mentioned the results I get in comments for each line. Can someone tell me how to resolve this..

```
var d = new Date(9999, 11, 31);
var sDateString = d.toLocaleDateString();//RETURNED "12/31/9999"
var aResult = sDateString.split("/");
console.log(aResult);//THIS GAVE THE RESULT ["‎12‎", "‎31‎", "‎9999"]
console.log(aResult[0]);//THIS GAVE THE RESULT 12. THIS IS AS EXPECTED
console.log(aResult[0]=="12");//RESULT IS false!!. MY EXPECTATION WAS ture HERE
console.log(aResult[0]==="12");//RESULT IS false!!. MY EXPECTATION WAS ture HERE
console.log(parseInt(aResult[0].trim()));//RESULT IS NaN!!. I EXPECTED NUMBER 12
```

Regards,

Fahad Hamsa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, IE11 adds `\u200e` characters - which is *`Unicode Character 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK'`* - see [this](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm)

so

```
var sDateString = d.toLocaleDateString();
```

results in `sDateString` being `*12*/*31*/*9999` - where `*` is `\u200e`

simplest fix

```
var sDateString = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString().replace(/\u200e/g, '');
```

this **wont** break real browsers, but it should fix stupid ones :p

Comment: That solved the issue.. Thanks a lot..

When I printed, I could not see anything which could have caused this issue. To be double sure about the data, I used trim(). I am wondering why trim() also did not work here. Is this special character is something which is out of reach for trim() also. 

split() being a JS method, it's so sad to see each browser interpret JS methods in it's own way.. :(
How did you get to know about this issue and solution?. Is there any documentation available

Comment: trim trims **spaces** ... so, these marker characters are not considered a space - how did I know about this? I tried reproducing your problem ... I copy/pasted the code (with your comments) and immediately in my editor saw the "additional" characters - fortunately, you copy/pasted from IE console, otherwise it would not have been obvious - so, I didn't **know**, but your copy/paste made it visible :p

Comment: I was trying in IE console where it did not indicate anything about special characters. Also, did not see any indication on notepad++ too..
Which editor did you use..

Comment: sorry, I was vague, I didn't see **what** the characters actually are in notepad++,  only that they existed ... see, I had a new document open, with encoding set to ANSI (new computer, I usually have my new documents set to UTF-8 - another stroke of luck!!) only because it was set to ANSI did I see the question marks, usually you can't see those characters in notepad++ at all - anyway, the ? made me curious, I posted your code in JSFIDDLE - and that's where the value of those hidden characters is shown